# Security question for iphone login form

Tags: php, iphone, security, forms

`iphone.php?email=%@&password=%@` Is there any issues with sending sensitive data over the airwaves like this from an Iphone login form?  Should the password be hashed before sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an issue? Yes! If the users connect through an unencrypted wifi in a coffee shop, everyone can read the credentials. That is *really* bad, especially if you consider that the average user probably uses one password for all his accounts.

Should the password be hashed? A simple hashing, like sending the md5 sum of the password, would not help, because an attacker could simply replay the attack.

My recommendation: don't try to invent your own encryption solution, switch to SSL.

Comment: Just a quick question.  The only thing I know about SSL is you get the certificate for your server which gives you the https.  Is there further coding needed with the iphone or is it just a more secure means of communicating?

Comment: As long as you get a valid SSL certificate, the only thing you have to change in your code is the URL. "Valid" means that the certificate is signed by a trusted authority, and not a self signed certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It would help alot to hash it before sending , it would allso help if you hash the field too and send the values via post ( if you can ) . It would allos help to have another hased hidden field witch would be recived from the server when the form is requested .

Comment: bare in mind that in order to get accepted into the itunes app store they have limits on what you can encrypt and what algorithms you can use

Comment: don't know anything about iphone apps and iphone store and how to get accepted , i know about php and from my point of view that's how things should work , that's why i sayd "if you can" , but it looks like you could check the limits on what you can encrypt and what algoritms you are allowed to use .